# Creating Objects With Caliburn Events Behind Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn

At the moment I create my object on the XAML side of the application. But I'm looking to create the objects programmatically to make the software more customizable and flexible.

XAML side

```xml
<Grid cal:Message.Attach="[MouseUp] = [AddBusiness]">
    <Rectangle Fill="DarkOliveGreen"/>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.BusinessCard}" Width="70"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewBusiness}" FontSize="14"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem I'm currently having is with attaching the Caliburn event to my Grid from code behind. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code should look like

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" cal:Message.Attach="[MouseUp] = [AddBusiness]">
    <Rectangle Fill="DarkOliveGreen"/>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.BusinessCard}" Width="70"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewBusiness}" FontSize="14"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code representation of the Attach

```
var grid = MyGrid; // assuming this is code behind of above view
Message.SetAttach(grid, "[MouseUp] = [AddBusiness]");
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't answer my question. This is for creating objects on the xaml side of the application. I'm looking to create the objects programatically. How would I attach "cal:Message.Attach" to my Grid. For example `var grid = new Grid();`

Comment: all good, it doesn't have to be caliburn, I've just never created an object with click events that trigger the viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help =)